# Show all terms of a vocaboulary

Tags: 7, theming, taxonomy-terms

I have this function that I used in a similar situation ([Drupal show all terms of different vocabulary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744736/drupal-show-all-terms-of-different-vocabulary/5746014#5746014)) that prints the terms of a node with a corresponding parent (if applicable). In my template.php file:

```
function theme479_print_terms($node, $vid = NULL, $ordered_list = TRUE) {
     $vocabularies = taxonomy_get_vocabularies();
     if ($ordered_list) $output .= '<ul>'; //checks to see if you want an ordered list
     if ($vid) { //checks to see if you've passed a number with vid, prints just that vid
        $output = '<div class="tags-'. $vid . '">';
        foreach($vocabularies as $vocabulary) {
         if ($vocabulary->vid == $vid) {
           $terms = taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary($node, $vocabulary->vid);
           if ($terms) {
             $links = array();
             $output .= '<span class="only-vocabulary-'. $vocabulary->vid . '">';
             if ($ordered_list) $output .= '<li class="vocabulary-'. $vocabulary->vid . '">' . $vocabulary->name . ': ';
             foreach ($terms as $term) {
              // Check for terms parent, if found assign to $parent variable
              if ($get_parents = taxonomy_get_parents($term->tid, 'tid')) {
                foreach ($get_parents as $parents) {
                  $parent = $parents->name . '/';
                }
              }
               $links[] = '<span class="term-' . $term->tid . '">' . l($parent . $term->name, taxonomy_term_path($term), array('rel' => 'tag', 'title' => strip_tags($term->description))) .'</span>';
             }
             $output .= implode(', ', $links);
             if ($ordered_list) $output .= '</li>';
             $output .= '</span>';
           }
         }
       }
     }
     else {
       $output = '<div class="tags">';
       foreach($vocabularies as $vocabulary) {
         if ($vocabularies) {
           $terms = taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary($node, $vocabulary->vid);
           if ($terms) {
             $links = array();
             $output .= '<ul class="vocabulary-'. $vocabulary->vid . '">';
             if ($ordered_list) $output .= '<li class="vocabulary-'. $vocabulary->vid . '">' . $vocabulary->name . ': ';
             foreach ($terms as $term) {
              // Check for terms parent, if found assign to $parent variable
              if ($get_parents = taxonomy_get_parents($term->tid, 'tid')) {
                foreach ($get_parents as $parents) {
                  $parent = $parents->name . '/';
                }
              }
               $links[] = '<span class="term-' . $term->tid . '">' . l($parent . $term->name, taxonomy_term_path($term), array('rel' => 'tag', 'title' => strip_tags($term->description))) .'</span>';
             }
             $output .= implode(', ', $links);
             if ($ordered_list) $output .= '</li>';
             $output .= '</ul>';
           }
         }
       }
     }
     if ($ordered_list) $output .= '</ul>';
     $output .= '</div>';
     return $output;
}
```

I have this vocabulary structure:

- Foods

  - Fruits
  - Fruit_with_seeds

This function only shows:

- Fruits

  - Fruit_with_seeds

Is it possible to show the entire hierarchy of a vocabulary?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for. The taxonomy terms for a node are normally nested inside `$node->taxonomy`. If you want all the terms "above" the terms inside the node, you should take a look at [taxonomy_get_tree()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/6). 
To the code above: I would urge you to seperate the tree-logic from the output; first create the array, then render the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = db_query('SELECT DISTINCT(tn.nid), t.tid, t.name, n.nid, n.title 
FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {term_node} tn ON n.nid = tn.nid 
INNER JOIN {term_data} t ON tn.tid = t.tid ORDER BY n.nid DESC');

while ($o = db_fetch_object($result)) {
  $items[$o->tid][] = l($o->title, 'node/' . $o->nid);
  $terms[$o->tid] = $o->name;
}

if (isset($items)) {
  foreach ($items as $tid => $item) {
    echo theme('item_list', $item, $terms[$tid]);
  }
}
```